# Консольная команда (Windows) для открытия текущей папки в phpStorm?

Tags: bash, phpstorm, cmd, jetbrains

Хочется, чтобы написав команду типа:

```
pstorm .
```

Открывалась текущая папка в пхпшторме. Создавал свой *.cmd файлик в прописанной в PATH директории, но не работает. Открывает шторм, но папку не распознает. Как быть нещасным владельцам Видновс?

**Немного инфы:**

Сам(exe) лежит тут:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.2\bin\phpstorm64.exe
```

Список файлов:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы параметр передаёте в CMD?
Вообще, вот так должно работать:

**pstorm.cmd**:

```
"C:\Somewhere\PhpStorm\bin\phpstorm64.exe" %1
```

http://recordit.co/fEp1tnFHrV